# Angular: FormControl in FormArray are not triggering validation functions

Tags: angular, forms

Imagine the following `FormGroup` in Angular:

```js
this.form = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(''),
  age: new FormControl(),
  hobbies: new FormArray([])
}, {
  validators: [this.validateForm.bind(this)]
});
```

I am later adding hobbies in `FormArray` using:

```js
this.form.controls.hobbies.controls.push(new FormControl(/* hobby */));
```

When I change values in `name` and `age` controls, the `validateForm` function is triggering fine. But when I click on either of the `hobbies`, aforementioned validation method isn't getting called.

Comment: What does this.validateForm look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out (it was a stupid mistake at my end).

Instead of adding new `FormControl` using:

```js
this.form.controls.hobbies.controls.push(new FormControl(/* hobby */))
```

I should've added it on the `hobbies` itself, e.g.

```js
const hobbies = this.form.controls.hobbies as FormArray;
hobbies.push(new FormControl(/* hobby */));
```

Above code adds to the same `controls` array, but Angular does a bunch of internal stuff to register the control with itself. So in previous solution, a new control would be added to the `hobbies`, but Angular won't know about it. But in the new, Angular will handle the stuff for us internally.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you need to pupulate the formArray with a formGroup for example:

```
  form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    skills: new FormArray([
      new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(''),
        level: new FormControl('')
      })
    ])
  });
```

you can find some good explanation here:

https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Having `formGroup` inside a `formArray` would defeat the intended purpose I chose `formArray` for in the first place, i.e. add new `FormControl` dynamically and loop to display new controls.